# ASP.NET 4.5.1 MVC 5 application not loading in browser. Failed to open http://

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, webdeploy, intranet

### Problem

I am using windows authentication with MVC5 ASP.NET application. When I went to the url of the application on my intranet, I typed in (just for example), http://derp.herp.edu. As expected, it 
asked me for my login credentials on the domain. I entered these.

I then get a completely blank page. No error message. Just a white screen. I then fired up the debugger in my browser and it simply states:

Failed to open http://derp.herp.edu

### Details

I don't even know where to find an error for this? I have no clue to what is causing this. I've been trying to look for logs, but since I am new to IIS7.5 I am not sure I am looking at the right ones. 
I just deployed the MVC5 on an IIS7.5 Windows 2008 R2 server. It is my belief that the IIS I am trying to deploy this on is on a secured VLAN.

### Attempts

- Launched locally on my machine IIS7.5. It works. What the heck?
- Moved to wwwroot of the inetpub file to make sure file permissions are okay on server.
- Associated the default web site on IIS7.5 to the domain name. I can see it on my local machine and the server in the browser.

Thus, we know the domain name works. We know that authentication is trying to work. But something is going wrong when it tries to display the MVC 5 .NET application.

Comment: Note that you're opening application locally! no domain name service available to resolve target!

Comment: I am sorry my explanation confused you. I tested my code/application on my local machine. I then deployed on a Windows 8 2012 R2 server (IIS7.5) which has a domain name. So I typed in the domain name, http://derp.herp.edu and it asked for authentication and then just showed a blank page. Nothing.

Comment: make sure your host supports MVC dependencies or you have uploaded necessary files due to work in every host without MVC support :)

Comment: You can check the logs of related server to understand what happened.

Comment: I think I should point out that I am using the default windows authentication template. So I am really confused as to why this can be run on my development computer, but fails to deploy on W2008 R2 IIS7.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the error. It was a completely silent error as the browser was just sitting there not doing anything. I started checking IIS and noticed that .NET compilation had some problems. I found the fix at [ASPNET4BreakingChangesAndStuffToBeAwareOf](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET4BreakingChangesAndStuffToBeAwareOf.aspx).